# Song identification request, likely from Touhou

Tags: music, touhou-project

I was recently watching a stream of one of my favourite League of Legends streamers, and he had a really good song in the background which sounded like it was from Touhou game.

[Here's](http://www.twitch.tv/lolgeranimo/v/3616880?t=28m58s) a link to the stream at the time the song is playing (~29:20).

What is the name of this song?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *Plain Asia* arrangement by **Dark PHOENiX** for their album *Arrow Rain*. In your video, the song starts at 27:53. You can verify that it is the song [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzRakY0oli0).

Comment: Wow thank you so much was really looking for this one!

Comment: Wiki: [Dark PHOENiX](https://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Dark_PHOENiX), [Arrow Rain](https://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Arrow_Rain)

Answer (score 2):

It's "Plain Asia" in [Touhou Eiyashou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperishable_Night).

But I think this is not original version.
I'm not sure which arrange version it is.